# How to pass url arguments to Flask behind Nginx proxy_pass with unix socket

Tags: python, nginx, flask, unix-socket

I have a Flask app with bjoern as python server. An example url I have is something like:

```
http://example.com/store/junihh
http://example.com/store/junihh/product-name
```

Where "junihh" and "product-name" are arguments that I need to pass to python.

I try to use unix socket after reading about the performance against TCP/IP calls. But now I get a 502 error on the browser.

This is an snippet of my conf:

```
upstream backend {
    # server localhost:1234;
    # server unix:/run/app_stores.sock weight=10 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
    server unix:/run/app_stores.sock;
}

server {
    listen                      80 default_server;
    listen                      [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name                 example.com www.example.com; 
    root                        /path/to/my/public;

    location ~ ^/store/(.*)$ {
        include                 /etc/nginx/conf.d/jh-proxy-pass.conf;
        include                 /etc/nginx/conf.d/jh-custom-headers.conf;

        proxy_pass              http://backend/$1;
    }
}
```

How to pass the url arguments to Flask through Nginx proxy_pass with unix socket?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my conf, it can works. 502 is because it cannot find route to the upstream server(ie. change http://127.0.0.1:5000/$1 to http://localhost:5000/$1) will cause 502.

#### nginx.conf

```
http {
    server {
        listen       80; 
        server_name  localhost;

        location ~ ^/store/(.*)$ {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/$1;
        }   
    }   
}
```

#### flask app.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def world():
    return 'world'

@app.route('/<name>/<pro>')
def shop(name, pro):
    return 'name: ' + name + ', prod: ' + pro

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

## Update

or you can use unix socket like this, but relay on *uwsgi*.

#### nginx.conf

```
http {
    server {
        listen       80; 

        location /store {
            rewrite /store/(.+) $1 break;
            include uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/store.sock;
        }   
    }   
}
```

#### flask app.py

like above, not change

#### uwsgi config

```
[uwsgi]
module=app:app
plugins=python3
master=true
processes=1
socket=/tmp/store.sock

uid=nobody
gid=nobody

vaccum=true
die-on-term=true
```

save as `config.ini`, then run `uwsgi config.ini`

after nginx reload, you can visit your page ;-)

Comment: I preferred to write my code with TCP / IP as I had before, very similar to your example. After all it is what worked for me before "flirting" with unix socket.